# Spark-submit fails without an error

Tags: java, apache-spark, word-count

I used the following command to run the spark java example of wordcount:-

```
time spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master spark://192.168.0.7:7077 --class org.apache.spark.examples.JavaWordCount /home/pi/Desktop/example/new/target/javaword.jar /books_500.txt
```

I have copied the same jar file into all nodes in the same location. (Copying into HDFS didn't work for me.) When I run it, the following is the output:-

```
Running Spark using the REST application submission protocol.
16/07/14 16:32:18 INFO rest.RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request to launch an application in spark://192.168.0.7:7077.
16/07/14 16:32:30 WARN rest.RestSubmissionClient: Unable to connect to server spark://192.168.0.7:7077.
Warning: Master endpoint spark://192.168.0.7:7077 was not a REST server. Falling back to legacy submission gateway instead.
16/07/14 16:32:30 WARN util.Utils: Your hostname, master02 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.0.7 instead (on interface wlan0)
16/07/14 16:32:30 WARN util.Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
16/07/14 16:32:31 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

It just stops there, quits the job and waits for the next command on terminal. I didn't understand this error without an error message. Help needed please...!!

Comment: Can you describe your setup? Single node / yarn-cluster / .. ?

Comment: What do you see in the master ui ?

Comment: First run in client mode and check for error logs.

Comment: I have a cluster of 16 raspberry pis on which I am trying to run spark. I have checked the GUI and it shows every completed job as failed. I have already tried to run it in client mode and it works fine, its log file is detailed, it shows the updates on processing of every block in the localnode. When I try to run in the cluster, (considering that the command I have passed is right), it gives the above output and stops abruptly.

Comment: Also, I'll let you know how I am running the system should it be of any help. I have 2 sizes of datasets with me, 50MB and 500MB files. I run each in client mode. Only the 50 MB runs fine. 500MB file seems to consume too much memory and the task is killed. I ran them in cluster mode but both of the file sizes show the same error.

Comment: The spark REST server is defaulted to port `6066`. Try `--master spark://192.168.0.7:6066`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429333/spark-submit-driver-is-running-on-worker-error